# Event prediction with quantitative Social Media Data (Time Series)

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, predictive-models, model, social-network

I want to use Twitter data to predict a boolean event. 
Let's say the Event is labeled as 1 (no event = 0).
I have several twitter datasets containing at least one timeframe with the event 1. A dataset consists of about 20,000 Twitter posts with several features (such as user information, likes, retweets, sentiment score,...).

Here a more clear example:

The dataset x start with posts from 01-Jan-2018 to 30-Mar-2018, all posts labeled as 0 (each observation has the above stated information). On 31-Mar-2018 at 3:22pm the event starts and lasts for 3 days. Within these 3 days (from exactly 3:22pm) all posts are labeled as 1 (Event = yes). After that, I've 3 more month of observations labeled as 0.

I've about 30 datasets from this kind, sometimes there are more than one event time-frame, maybe two or three.

My goal is to train models to detect as early as possible if the event occurs.

My idea so far:

Since one observation (=one post + information) can't predict the event alone, my idea is to aggregate 10 minute-chunks containing means of the aggregated data and volume information (total number of posts within these 10 minutes) and label them as 1 or 0. After that, I'd train machine learning algorithms on that cases and hope that it is able to predict the event with the aggregated data of 10 minutes.

My question(s) to you:

Do you think that it as an idea that can work? Or do you have any better suggestions or methods I should try? Furthermore, do you have any suggestion for how to choose the best length of the "chunks"? 10 Minutes was just an example, do you have any idea how to choose the length?

Cheers :)

Comment: the features information, likes, retweets are an indication for the event? does it not makes more sense to make a classification problem and analyse the features to say if it is an event or not? then you don't have the timing, but the moment the features are there you can predict if it is an event or not...

Comment: When I understand you correct, you mean to use the information within one observation and classify this observation as event or not? The problem here is, that there are several of this kind of observations within the whole dataset but not that concentrated as they are within the event. Thus, I need to aggregate the observations of x minutes because within the event these observations are more concentrated and I can get new features out of the aggregation such as "Mean xy within the last 10 minutes" what might be more reliable than just one observation.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you, but is it a 'panel timeseries' problem?